# Ruby Threading Won't Context Switch

Tags: ruby, alsa

Using MRI ruby 1.9 I have some code like

```
def foo()
  puts "in foo"
  loop do
    puts "in foo loop"
  end
end

def bar()
  puts "in bar"
  start_alsa_listener
end

foo_thread = Thread.new { foo }
bar_thread = Thread.new { bar }
foo_thread.join
bar_thread.join
```

start_alsa_listener is a blocking library call that opens the ALSA midi sequencer and waits for input events on it. Essentially, I want my code to be constantly printing out "in foo loop" and at the same time be able to receive ALSA midi events and print them out to the console as well (which start_alsa_listener does when it receives an event).

The problem is that when I run the code above, as soon as bar() runs it never context switches back to foo().

start_alsa_listener is a ruby C extension that looks like:

```
for(;;) {
    poll(/* args */);      /* wait for input data */
    /* print data to console */
}
```

Perhaps it is related to something in Ruby I am doing wrong with threading, or maybe something to do with poll, or maybe something to do with the way ALSA handles threads. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The loop you’ve shown will block the whole interpreter (assuming `poll` is blocking) like Steve said. You need to call poll() using [rb_thread_blocking_region](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_2/thread.c#L1069) from the Ruby (MRI/YARV) C API.

Answer (score 2):

Without the cext, those two do run in paralell. The GIL won't let two threads run at once with a C extension, because it can't know it's threadsafe.

Comment: they don't need to run in parallel per se, as long as they context switch in and out so that it feels like they are running in parallel. Is ruby doing something to prevent even this from happening?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, the C extension means that the GIL is being held by the thread with the c extension, which means other threads can't run.